# Can not upload any data to the database using php and Myadmin database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am making a prototype website for a recruitment agency and I am having a problem with uploading any data to the database which has been created for this prototype system. This is the register a new user page and it will not send any of the information in the html text fields to the database.

This is my code this far -

```
<?php
    require (__DIR__.'/connections/connections.php');

    if(isset($_POST['Register'])){ 

    session_start();
    $Title = $_POST['Consultant_Title'];
    $Fname = $_POST['Consultant_First_Name'];
    $Lname = $_POST['Consultant_Last_Name'];
    $Cbranch = $_POST['Consultant_Branch'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Username = $_POST['Username'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];


    $StorePassword = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));

    $spl = $con->query("INSERT INTO consultant_details (Title, Fname, Lname, Cbranch )Values('{$Title}', '{$Fname}', '{$Lname}', '{$Cbranch}')");

    $spl = $con->query("INSERT INTO users ( Email, Username, Password )Values('{$Title}', '{$Email}', '{$Username}', '{$StorePassword}')");

header('location: Login.php');
    }
?>
```

Html -

```
<h2>Staff Register </h2>
          <div class="clr"></div>
          <form action="" method="post" name="Registerform" id="Registerform">

          <div class="FormElement"><select style="font-size: medium;">
  <option name="Consultant_Title" id="Consultant_Title" value="Mr">Mr</option>
  <option name="Consultant_Title" id="Consultant_Title" value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
  <option name="Consultant_Title" id="Consultant_Title" value="Miss">Miss</option>
  <option name="Consultant_Title" id="Consultant_Title" value="Ms">Ms</option>
  <option name="Consultant_Title" id="Consultant_Title" value="Dr">Dr</option>
  <option name="Consultant_Title" id="Consultant_Title" value="Professor">Professor</option>
</select></div>

                <div class="FormElement">
          <input name="Consultant_First_Name" type="text" required="required" class="TField" id="Consultant_First_Name" placeholder="First Name"> <input name="Consultant_Last_Name" type="text" required="required" class="TField" id="Consultant_Last_Name" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>

        <div class="FormElement">
          <input name="Username" type="text" required="required" class="TField" id="Username" placeholder="Username"> <input name="Password" type="text" pattern=".{6,}" required title="6 characters minimum" class="TField" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>

        <div class="FormElement">
          <input name="Consultant_Branch" type="text" required="required" class="TField" id="Consultant_Branch" placeholder="Consultant Branch"> <input name="Email" type="text" required="required" class="TField" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <div class="FormElement"><input name="Register" type="submit" class="button" id="Register" value="Register"></div>
        </form>
```

Comment: your `<select>` should have the name attribute, not the `<option>` also you're not giving us enough information to really help you

Comment: What would you like to know ?

Comment: like @Elyor said, are you getting any errors? and also what is $con? Turn on error reporting if you're not seeing any errors.

Comment: I am not getting a error when I register a new user nothing happened it just doesn't upload any data to the db. so I am at a loss as to why it will not upload data inputted into the said html fields. I thought maybe I did something obviously wrong maybe someone could point it out.

Comment: *I am not getting a error*, well are you looking for one? Do you have error reporting enabled? @eddyrailgun

Comment: check your error using like `mysqli_error($con)`

Comment: Have you tried what @ElefantPhace commented? this seems to me to be the answer

Comment: besides what's already been said; you're attempting to do a multi query; that isn't how it's done.

Comment: Plus, you have errors, look at your 2nd query ***very carefully.*** - do the math here ;-)

Comment: Lol ya the multi query was an experiment to see if it would help getting something upload to the db. ya error reporting is on, its not reading any errors :/.

Comment: all of the above will result in a solution. I might even submit an answer, but as a WIKI, I said "might". ;-)

Comment: This is a dumb question, but just to make sure, is the PHP code located on the same page as the HTML?

Comment: Ya if you could submit a solution that be great help fred thx you.

Comment: I have decided to post it as a wiki after @eddyrailgun

Comment: ya the php and html are both located on the same page.

Comment: try using `var_dump();` in different locations to see what outputs. I would start with `var_dump($_POST);`  at the top of you PHP to make sure everything is sent properly

Comment: As I am sure everyone has guessed im new to php and Mysqli aha, ok il do my reading and see if I can now get it to work. Thanks for taking the time to help me guys, I'l report back on how I have got on and how I might have managed to solve it also :D

Comment: Thx guys for the help, really helped. I found out the database it self was to blame.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in comments, `<select>` holds the name attribute, not `<option>`. The value(s) will then populate from the one(s) given for `value="x"`.

Then you have 3 columns and 4 values in your second query (missing column for "title") and attempting to perform a [multi-query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Consult these following links

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

and apply that to your code.

Another thing, since you're using `password_hash()`, use a prepared statement with that.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- MySQLi: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

You are open to SQL injection. Consult the following on Stack:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Your connection is also unknown, whether it is MySQL_, or MySQLi_ or PDO.

Different APIs do not intermix, so use the same MySQL API from connection to query, *call it an insight*.

To check if a query *truly* was successful, use `affected_rows()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

PHP has a set of functions specifically for handling password hashes.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Read [this tutorial](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to see how you can put these things into action.

Answer (score 0):

first put name attribute in select tag

```
<div class="FormElement"><select name="Consultant_Title" style="font-size: medium;">
  <option id="Consultant_Title" value="Mr">Mr</option>
  <option id="Consultant_Title" value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
  <option id="Consultant_Title" value="Miss">Miss</option>
  <option id="Consultant_Title" value="Ms">Ms</option>
  <option id="Consultant_Title" value="Dr">Dr</option>
  <option id="Consultant_Title" value="Professor">Professor</option>
</select></div>
```

second missed mentioning title in your query and you gave it in values

```
$spl = $con->query("INSERT INTO users ( Title, Email, Username, Password ) Values('{$Title}', '{$Email}', '{$Username}', '{$StorePassword}')");
```

Answer (score 0):

**After each query try to handle any mysql error regarding your queries.**

Example.

```
$spl = $con->query("INSERT INTO users ( Email, Username, Password ) 
                    Values ('{$Title}', '{$Email}', '{$Username}', '{$StorePassword}')"  
       or die(mysqli_error($con)));
```

**This will guide you in dealing with your mysql errors.**

Comment: Noble, yet it is not the issue here. It will indeed help though and I fixed that in your answer. See the edit comment and the wiki that I posted to outline the errors.